# Set all the images horizontally

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I have the problem.

By using the following function:

```
 Private Sub SizeToRange(ByVal targetShape As Shape, ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Adjust picture properties
    With targetShape
        ' Check if next line is required...
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = Target.Left + 15
        .Top = Target.Top - 4
        .Width = Target.Width - 30
        .Height = Target.Height
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack

        '.IncrementRotation Deg
    End With

    ' Adjust picture border properties
    With targetShape.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

and the code:

```
 Public Sub ResizeChambers()

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim targetShape As Shape


' Define the sheet that has the pictures
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Define the range the images is going to fit
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("E3:I16")

' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes

    ' Check "picture" word in name
    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
        targetShape.Flip msoFlipHorizontal
    End If

Next targetShape

End Sub
```

I am trying to set all my images on horizontal way.

As you can see I used both options:
 1. `targetShape.Flip msoFlipHorizontal` for the code
 2. `.IncrementRotation Deg`  for function

In both cases doesn't work, because one images are horizontal and another ones are vertical and another way round.

[image]

How can I make all of them in horizontal alignment?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in different ways, by using `Shape Range Collection Object`, and either use `Shepes.SelectAll`, or Select each type of shape object, without using the `Replace` argument, or select a specific `Range`. Change the type of shape and range as needed. If you have any questions, please ask.

**Example 1:** Use Shape Range collection Object

```
Dim shprng As ShapeRange

ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
Set shprng = Selection.ShapeRange

shprng.Align 3, 0 '3 is the enumeration for msoPicture, and 0 is the enumeration for msoFalse
```

**Example 2:** Select the type of shape

```
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = 13 Then shp.Select False '13 is the enumeration for msoPicture
Next shp

With Selection.ShapeRange
    .Align 3, 0 '3 is the enumeration for msoALignTops, and 0 is the enumeration for msoFalse
End With
```

**Example 3:** Use a specific Range

```
Dim shp As Shape, rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:O20")

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(Range(shp.TopLeftCell, shp.BottomRightCell), rng) Is Nothing And shp.Type = 13 Then shp.Select False '13 is the enumeration for msoPicture
Next shp

With Selection.ShapeRange
    .Align 3, 0 '3 is the enumeration for msoALignTops, and 0 is the enumeration for msoFalse
End With
```

Comment: Hi I tried your codes and none of them was working properly.
Nonethelles I think, that error is minor. If I used the last code for instance (which was the best suitable for me) all the images were selected, but 2 of them are still in vertical position. I am not sure about the shp.Type = 13 then shp.select.false. What does it mean? All of the images were selected. If I put true here, then debugger shown error under the line .Align 3,0. Could be possible to clarify?

Comment: If you are just trying to rotate one of the images then: You have to select the image first. excel can't tell which image you want to rotate unless you identify it, use `Set Pict = Sh.Shapes(1)' 'Pict.IncrementRotation 90'

Comment: I think, that this can be somewhat a hint. Unfortunnately I never know what type of pics will coming in. For the time being I can stick to you advice. Thanks